# OpenSolaris/x86 responding sluggishly - frequent freezing

Tags: performance, solaris, opensolaris, debugging

The system starts up fine, and for about 5 minutes (est.) things are fine.  Then the system starts to get very sluggish ("choppy"): the mouse will freeze for two or three seconds, then release for about one to two seconds.  I've tried using DTrace, but so far to no avail: I'm still learning DTrace and finding out what I should be looking for.

The system is an HP nc4010 Pentium M based laptop, and I installed the system using the text mode - running the GUI on a remote X server.

The CPU utilization consistently (at the height of difficulties) is almost constantly at 80-95% in system operations.  There is always idle time: anywhere from 7 to 90 percent, depending on usage.

I've looked around a bit but haven't come up with anyting.  No messages in messages log.

What do you recommend?

Comment: You mention "... I installed the system using the text mode - running the GUI on a remote X server." Are you still using the remote X server, or are you running a local X server and that is where the problem happens?

Does it happen to more than one user?  root user or one you created?

Comment: Nope: switched to local X server.  System has one user: me.

Interesting addition: running without networking (no ethernet connected, no wireless in range) meant I could do things without interruption.

Is it possible the network drivers are interrupting too much, or are processing the data in a bad way?  Sounds like a question for DTrace....

Answer (score 1):

I found that the problem was either the wireless networking or ethernet networking.  I've since overwritten this installation with Solaris 2009.06 (released a couple of days ago) and haven't experienced this problem so far.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with running prstat (top) to see if you can determine if there is a specific process that is causing the slowdown.

Comment: I used top straight-away - first thing.  Busiest job took about 0.8% of the CPU.